# Why angular ngIf directive need bracket if we don't want bind it to component field?

Tags: angular, angular-directive

why we need bracket if we don't want to bind attribute directive to a component field.

for example why the below code is not working:

```
<ng-template ngIf=false>
     <h3>Test</h3>
</ng-template>
```

if we use bracket ([ngIf]=false), it is working, but as I know bracket is use when we want to bind http tag attribute or directive to component variable

For example ngClass directive work fine without bracket:

```
<h2 ngClass='myclass'>title</h2>
```

Comment: Because then it comes a string, i.e. `"false"`, which is a truthy value. (Also, it should be `*ngIf`)

Comment: even with "" it is not working

Comment: It does? As I say, it should be `*ngIf=""`, which will hide the element. Make sure you include the `*`

Comment: Actually, having just checked it works with the `*ngIf="false"` as well, so my assumption was incorrect.

Comment: we don't need * here because I use ng-template

Comment: Okay, fair point, but it will hide it with an empty string https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mszbx5

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: when using ngIf without brackets - you evaluate a string.
and since any string other than an empty string evaluates to true, the element is shown.

**Long answer**: 
When you place an `*ngIf="boolean"` on an element, say a div, then it's exactly the same as doing this:

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="boolean">
     <div> ... </div>
</ng-template>
```

So far so good, you can and probably did already read this from [angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#asterisk).
So oddly enough, you didn't want to sugar coat it, and went straight to using `ng-template` yourself.

Now you ask, what happens if I remove the brackets, de-facto, throwing away the one-way binding. and simply setting a value to that ngIf directive.

What happens is the exact behavior that happens when you use other attributes on elements. say, `[class]`. if you use `[class]="text-red"` on an element. you'll get a get a class named undefined on your element. you just tried to use an undefined object as your class name.

so if we assume this CSS rule is in effect:

```
.text-red { color: red }
```

**when not using brackets, it expects a string.**

```
<div class="text-red"> I AM RED </div>  // text is red
```

**when using brackets, it expects an expression**, add apostrophe to express a string.

```
<div [class]="'text-red'"> I AM RED </div>  // text is red
```

hope this makes things a bit clearer